# My 1440x900 resolution looks stretched

Tags: display, resolution

I just upgraded my PC:

My old one can only support up to **1280x800** and everything looks fine. But when I upgraded and now it can support up to **1440x900** but the problm is, it looks stretched vertically. The usually square now looks a standing rectangle.

How could I fix my display?

Comment: These resolutions are the same ratio (1.6:1) they should look the same. Are there black bars on either side of the monitor? What type of monitor is it? It sounds like you need to change your monitors settings.

Comment: My monitor is a `viewsonic vx1937wma`. I'm not sure if it was `1280x800` but it's `1280xsomething`

Comment: The native resolution should be 1440x900 for viewsonic vx1937wma. Have you tried "auto adjust" the monitor?

Comment: `1440x900` is the native reolution so it should be fine. How are you connecting? VGA/DVI/HDMI/DP? Try just hitting the `Auto` button. Try disconnecting the display output and reconnecting it.

Comment: Yes I tried the auto button but it still looks elongated.

Comment: also, would it be okay if I go beyond the native resolution of my monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Just from some simple math I can tell you it won't look right, if you expand the image 50 on the sides, and 80 up and down you will no longer have the same ratio.  1440x900 is the native resolution, so you might just have to try some other resolutions till you find one you like.  http://www.viewsonic.com.au/product_pdfs/lcd/19/E-VX1937wm.pdf

Comment: The ratios are the same - 1:1.6

Comment: My resolution was to downgrade to `1280x1024` :(